# Algorithm to generate top N% of permutations with most dissimilarities

Tags: algorithm, permutation, similarity

Let us consider a set of data with, say, 10 values. We need to estimate its characterstics by Monte Carlo method, that is with a large number of randomly generated permutated sets.

If we'd consider generation of all possible permutations, that would give too big number, almost impractical - even for 10 values *n!* is 3628800. We can generate a (relatively small) subset of permutations randomly, but this does not take into account that permutations are not equally "distinct".

Here we come to the question: is there an algorithm of permutations generation which would count permutations' dissimilarity and produce most noticable permutations first (so that we can stop it after, say, 1000 cycles)?

I don't have specific requirements on the "similarity" measure, so if anything like a distance, information gain, entropy, Spearman, etc. are involved, that's would be ok.

Currently I'm doing one random permutation like so (pseudocode):

```cpp
void permutate(const int n, int &out[])
{
  for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k) out[k] = k;
  for(int k = 0; k < n - 1; ++k)
  {
    int i1 = rand() % (n - k - 1) + 1;
    swap(out, k, k + i1);
  }
}
```

and run this predefined number of times.

Here the probability of swapping neighbouring values is the same as swapping distant values.

Comment: This sounds to me like a set cover problem.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to generate permutations iteratively, but at every iteration, you forbid element i from being at position j if it has already been in position j in a previously generated matching. Keep iterating until no permutation exists that satisfies this constraint.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality is your friend. It is hard for random permutations to be close to each other in any meaningful way. I'd actually worry more that an attempt to avoid it will cause some subtle structural features to get replicated.